# ASP.NET Web API - ActionFilter Property not being set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a base controller class that extends from `ApiController` and specifies this abstract method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateModelFilter(Argument = "dto")]
public abstract Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(PostDTO dto);
```

This method will be implemented by all the child classes, but the filter will be implictly applied without them realizing.

This approach works fine, my filter is executed. But my `Argument` property is not being set to `"dto"`.

This is my `ValidateModelFilter` class:

```
public class ValidateModelFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IFilter
{
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
         //Some validation here...
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that my `Argument` property is always `null`, whether I apply the filter like this: `[ValidateModelFilter]` or this `[ValidateModelFilter(Argument = "dto")]`

Please, also note that I'm currently using an `OWIN` pipeline and `Ninject` for dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, I managed to solve the problem.

I was registering my filter in my application's configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
    configuration.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelFilter());
}
```

This makes it **"Global"** and is ***always*** executed, whether you have that filter annotation or not.

I commented that line and now my filter works fine.

```
//configuation.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelFilter());
```